# Fibonacci sequence output

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, fibonacci-sequence

Here's the code I'm having trouble shortening. I am currently a beginner in Python 3.x.

```
from os import system

def fibonacci(terms):
    count = 0
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = x + y
    if terms <= 0:
        print("Enter a positive integer.")
    elif terms == 1:
        print("Fibonacci sequence in " + str(terms) + " terms.")
        print(x)
    else:
        print("Printing " + str(terms) + " terms.")
        while count < terms:
            print(x)
            z = x + y
            x = y
            y = z
            count += 1

while True:
    user_input = int(input("How many terms? "))
    fibonacci(user_input)
    loop = input("Again? (Y/n) ")
    if loop == "Y" or loop == "":
        system("cls")
    else:
        exit()
```

I would appreciate if there will be someone who will be able to make this as efficient as possible.

Comment: Ahoy! Welcome to code review. I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/252485/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Separate responsibilities

Your functions should, where possible, limit themselves to doing one thing only. This is the  [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). In case of `fibonacci()`, I expect this function to just calculate the desired Fibonacci number, and not deal with user input and output. This shortens the function and makes it easier to reason about. So:

```
def fibonacci(terms):
    count = 0
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = x + y

    while count < terms:
        yield x
        z = x + y
        x = y
        y = z
        count += 1
```

Instead of printing the values, it `yield`s them. To print the values, use the following:

```
terms = int(input("How many terms? "))
for number in fibonacci(terms):
    print(number)
```

You can even go futher and make `fibonacci()` an infinite generator, and leave it up to the caller to decide when to stop:

```
import itertools

def fibonacci():
    x = 0
    y = 1

    while True:
        yield x
        z = x + y
        x = y
        y = z

terms = int(input("How many terms? "))
for number in itertools.islice(fibonacci(), terms):
    print(number)
```

Here I used [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to take only the first `terms` items from the generator.

If you want to handle invalid input gracefully, I suggest you write another function whose responsibility is asking the user for a postivive integer:

```
def get_positive_integer(prompt):
    while True:
        user_input = int(input(prompt))
        if ...:            
            return user_input
        print("Enter a positive integer.")
```

## Avoid using `os.system()`

Using `os.system()` to clear the screen is very inefficient and not portable. Of course it is prettier to clear the screen, but if it is not really important for your program, I would just not do it; portability is more important.

Comment: as an addition OP constructs: `print("Fibonacci sequence in " + str(terms) + " terms."` could use `format` instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Format is old, f-strings are good

Comment: yeah, unless you're stuck with a legacy version of python.

Comment: One drawback of f-strings is that they don't really work well in combination with [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797658/how-to-use-gettext-with-python-3-6-f-strings).

Answer (score 6):

```
        z = x + y
        x = y
        y = z
```

is not idiomatic Python. Consider

```
        x, y = y, x + y
```

---

Regarding optimization, since you want *all* terms, there is not much to optimize. *If* wanted a *specific* term, a matrix exponentiation would be a way to go.